# MongDB with Mongoose -Select a specified date range discarding time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema consisting of an array of elements with a date field

```
var querySchema  = new Schema({
        id         : String,
        description: String,
        results    : [{
            date  : { type: Date, default: new Date },
            result: Object
        }]
});
```

When i add new elements i use the `New Date`. Resulting in elements like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b96289c9dcbe79207c4b08"),
    "id" : "11",
    "description" : "List of graphs loaded in the KB (24 graphs as of 09/05/2015 + 5 default Virtuoso graphs)",
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "result" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("55b96289c9dcbe79207c4b09"),
            "date" : ISODate("2015-07-29T22:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "result" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("55b962e05489d4de20a99f87"),
            "date" : ISODate("2015-07-31T22:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "result" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("55b963284f5083492119ef5b"),
            "date" : ISODate("2015-08-29T22:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I would like to find results that fall within a specific date range regardless of the time. What i want to do is accept user input on the range he wants through query parameters, if not then the range will be for todays elements.

```
    router.route('/aggregate')

      .get(function(req, res) {

        if (req.param('id')) {

            // Extract the date range filterin query paramteres if they were passed
            var start = new Date(req.param('start')) || new Date;
            var end   = req.param('end') ? new Date(req.param('end')) : new Date;

            Query.aggregate([
                  {
                     "$match":
                     {
                                id            : req.param('id'),
                                "results.date": { "$lt": end, "$gt": start }
                     },
                  }],function(err,result) {
                            res.json(result);
                });

        } else res.json({message: 'Invalid request. Please specify a query ID'});
   });
```

I tried for example doing a call with parameters `?id=11&start="2014, 7, 31"` and it shows results from the 29th of july. Various queries are not working so i know there is something wrong.

I have tried various date formats, removing time be resetting it but nothing worked so far.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript `Date` object constructor for UTC times can take the input as a "String":

```
>  new Date("2014-07-31")
ISODate("2014-07-31T00:00:00Z")
```

But this is **not** correct:

```
> new Date(2015,7,31)
ISODate("2015-08-30T14:00:00Z")
```

Either is this:

```
> new Date("2015/7/31")
ISODate("2015-07-30T14:00:00Z")
```

There are other valid contructor values for UTC, such as a numeric value if that suits:

```
> new Date(1406764800000)
ISODate("2014-07-31T00:00:00Z")
```

Or simply round a date to the day like so:

```
> var date = new Date()
> date
ISODate("2015-07-30T01:42:23.631Z")
> new Date( date.valueOf() - ( date.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) )
ISODate("2015-07-30T00:00:00Z")
```

Those are your methods for working with a whole date without any hours minutes or seconds with the basic object contructor and values.

Contruct a UTC Date as a whole day and that should suit your selections.

Comment: Thanks @Blakes for the notes. However, this still did not solve my problem. MongoDB still cannot do date comparison for some reason. I have passed the date string a `2015/7/31` and i get `Mon Aug 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

Comment: @AhmadAssaf They are not notes, they are the "correct" way to set a `Date` contructor from a "string" or numeric value. The current strings you are sending will not form the correct value. Use the examples as I have above. Ie. "2015/7/31" Wrong! "2015-07-31" Correct!

Comment: sorry if the term "note" was not suitable. However, i did exactly that, i hardcoded the dates in the methods you specified `new Date("2015/7/31")` and `new Date(1406764800000)`. I am wondering if the Date type in MongoDB requires something specific because the comparison is not done.

Comment: ok .. sorry i understood that `new Date(2015,7,31)` is the correct way. The word either confused me, i guess you meant neither. I think its good now :)

Comment: Using the hardcoded values `"$lte": new Date("2015-08-31"), "$gte": new Date("2015-07-31")` should return dates greater than 31-7 but less than 31-8 (two values from the results set). However this is not working, i still guess its MongoDB related

Comment: @AhmadAssaf There is a difference between `"2015-8-31"` and `"2015-08-31"`. Which is exactly why the examples are presented that way.

Comment: I saw that and immediately edited my comment. Still the same result

Comment: @AhmadAssaf You are still doing something wrong that you are not making clear. Edit your question to show more details of what you are doing/trying and be sure to list the exact documents you are trying to match. If I take your samples given already, and put them in my own collection, then all date range matching works for me perfectly. Not a mongo problem. There is something you are not telling people,

Comment: Thanks for your help along the way. The problem was a missing `$unwind` in the aggregate pipeline. So i was getting the top document containing all the chile results. My bad, and thanks for your patience